# FullCalendar plugin 3.1.0 no se visualiza correctamente

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

No logro que *FullCalendar* se visualice de manera correcta en mi plantilla *blade* de *Laravel*, no sé qué estoy haciendo mal. El resultado que obtengo es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se supone debería verse así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy usando *Laravel 5.3*, *jQuery 2.2.3* y *Xampp*. Lo extraño es que al ejecutar las demos de *FullCalendar* se visualizan correctamente, pero cuando lo paso a una plantilla *blade* ya no se visualiza igual. Los archivos *CSS* y *JS*, se cargan correctamente, y la consola de depuración, no muestra ningún error. El código de la plantilla *blade* es el siguiente:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

 $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
  defaultDate: '2016-12-12',
  editable: true,
  eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
  events: [
   {
    title: 'All Day Event',
    start: '2016-12-01'
   },
   {
    title: 'Long Event',
    start: '2016-12-07',
    end: '2016-12-10'
   },
   {
    id: 999,
    title: 'Repeating Event',
    start: '2016-12-09T16:00:00'
   },
   {
    id: 999,
    title: 'Repeating Event',
    start: '2016-12-16T16:00:00'
   },
   {
    title: 'Conference',
    start: '2016-12-11',
    end: '2016-12-13'
   },
   {
    title: 'Meeting',
    start: '2016-12-12T10:30:00',
    end: '2016-12-12T12:30:00'
   },
   {
    title: 'Lunch',
    start: '2016-12-12T12:00:00'
   },
   {
    title: 'Meeting',
    start: '2016-12-12T14:30:00'
   },
   {
    title: 'Happy Hour',
    start: '2016-12-12T17:30:00'
   },
   {
    title: 'Dinner',
    start: '2016-12-12T20:00:00'
   },
   {
    title: 'Birthday Party',
    start: '2016-12-13T07:00:00'
   },
   {
    title: 'Click for Google',
    url: 'http://google.com/',
    start: '2016-12-28'
   }
  ]
    });
});
```

```css
body {
 margin: 40px 10px;
 padding: 0;
 font-family: "Lucida Grande",Helvetica,Arial,Verdana,sans-serif;
 font-size: 14px;
}

#calendar {
 max-width: 900px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset='utf-8' />
<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.1.0/fullcalendar.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.1.0/fullcalendar.print.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script src="http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-with-locales.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.1.0/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
</head>
 <body>
  <div id='calendar'></div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: resuelto o aun con el mismo problema?

Answer (score 1):

Solo es cuestión de eliminar la llamada a `fullcalendar.print.css` quitando esa linea se visualiza de manera correcta.

La librería `fullcalendar.print.css` lo que hace es mostrar el contenido oculto para poder imprimirlo, si este es el caso que necesitas imprimir el calendario puedes hacer:

1. Cargar la librería `fullcalendar.print.css` por javascript o jquery al momento de presionar un botón para después quitar esa librería.
2. Cargar una pagina diferente con los estilos cargados de `fullcalendar.print.css` e imprimir desde esa pagina (acción automática)

Tu código funcionando sin la librería `fullcalendar.print.css`:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

 $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
  defaultDate: '2016-12-12',
  editable: true,
  eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
  events: [
   {
    title: 'All Day Event',
    start: '2016-12-01'
   },
   {
    title: 'Long Event',
    start: '2016-12-07',
    end: '2016-12-10'
   },
   {
    id: 999,
    title: 'Repeating Event',
    start: '2016-12-09T16:00:00'
   },
   {
    id: 999,
    title: 'Repeating Event',
    start: '2016-12-16T16:00:00'
   },
   {
    title: 'Conference',
    start: '2016-12-11',
    end: '2016-12-13'
   },
   {
    title: 'Meeting',
    start: '2016-12-12T10:30:00',
    end: '2016-12-12T12:30:00'
   },
   {
    title: 'Lunch',
    start: '2016-12-12T12:00:00'
   },
   {
    title: 'Meeting',
    start: '2016-12-12T14:30:00'
   },
   {
    title: 'Happy Hour',
    start: '2016-12-12T17:30:00'
   },
   {
    title: 'Dinner',
    start: '2016-12-12T20:00:00'
   },
   {
    title: 'Birthday Party',
    start: '2016-12-13T07:00:00'
   },
   {
    title: 'Click for Google',
    url: 'http://google.com/',
    start: '2016-12-28'
   }
  ]
    });
});
```

```css
body {
 margin: 40px 10px;
 padding: 0;
 font-family: "Lucida Grande",Helvetica,Arial,Verdana,sans-serif;
 font-size: 14px;
}

#calendar {
 max-width: 900px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset='utf-8' />
<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.1.0/fullcalendar.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script src="http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-with-locales.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.1.0/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
</head>
 <body>
  <div id='calendar'></div>
 </body>
</html>
```