# Fullcalendar no se visualiza correctamente

Tags: javascript, html, css, laravel, fullcalendar

Tengo este calendario:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He querido duplicarlo, importante sus componentes, pero no se ve, vi este post donde me decian lo del fullcalendar.print.css pero aun eliminandolo sigue sin ponerse bien.

[FullCalendar plugin 3.1.0 no se visualiza correctamente](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/40272/fullcalendar-plugin-3-1-0-no-se-visualiza-correctamente)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguien sabria decirme que es lo que pasa? En consola no sale ningun error.

Codigo:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" class="loading">
<head>

    <!-- BEGIN VENDOR CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('css/bootstrap.css') }}">
    <!-- font icons -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ URL::asset('css/plugins/calendars/fullcalendar.min.css')}}"/>

    </head>
<body>
<!-- Full calendar advance example section start -->
<div class="app-content content container-fluid">
  <div class="content-wrapper">
    <!-- Full calendar advance example section start -->
    <div class="content-body">
      <section id="advance-examples">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="card-header">
                <h4 align= "center" class="card-title">Calendario</h4>
                <a class="heading-elements-toggle"><i class="icon-ellipsis font-medium-3"></i></a>
                <div class="heading-elements">
                  <ul class="list-inline mb-0">
                    <li><a data-action="collapse"><i class="icon-minus4"></i></a></li>
                    <li><a data-action="reload"><i class="icon-reload"></i></a></li>
                    <li><a data-action="close"><i class="icon-cross2"></i></a></li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="card-body collapse in">
                <div class="card-block">
                  <div class="row">

                    <div class="col-md-9">
                      <div id='fc-default'></div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
                <div class="card-header with-border">
                    <h4 align= "center" class="card-title"> </h4>
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>

    </div>
    <!-- // Full calendar advance section end -->
  </div>
  </section>

</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.11.2/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.7.0/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
<!-- // Full calendar advance section end -->



<script>

  $(function () {

    /* initialize the calendar
     -----------------------------------------------------------------*/
    //Date for the calendar events (dummy data)
    $('#fc-default').fullCalendar({
      header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
      },
      buttonText: {
        today: 'hoy',
        month: 'mes',
        week: 'semana',
        day: 'dia'
      },
      monthNames: ['Enero','Febrero','Marzo','Abril','Mayo','Junio','Julio','Agosto','Septiembre','Octubre','Noviembre','Diciembre'],
        monthNamesShort: ['Ene','Feb','Mar','Abr','May','Jun','Jul','Ago','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dic'],
        dayNames: ['Domingo','Lunes','Martes','Miércoles','Jueves','Viernes','Sábado'],
        dayNamesShort: ['Dom','Lun','Mar','Mié','Jue','Vie','Sáb'],

      //events: { url:"cargaEventos"},

    });
  });

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Verifica en el demo  de donde se encuentra la primera captura de pantalla de tu pregunta, el archivo css en el que se están tomando los estilos, una vez que identifiques el archivo, verifica en tu proyecto que efectivamente este presente archivo, y que los estilos no se estén sobreescribiendo con algunos otros...

Comment: Era cosa de los imports, he probado copiando la pagina que si se visualizaba el calendario, y tengo algun css o js que desde el layout padre no lo coje, tiene que estar definido en la hija, aunque me parece super extraño. Muchas gracias igualmente por tu ayuda